# I'm writing code to determine the state of water with if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, java.util.scanner, temperature

I'm writing code to determine the state of water depending on the temperature in celsius and altitude, how can I make it so at the end, if the altitude is more than 300, it takes 1 less degree celsius for the water to boil and the outcome can be determined depending on the input?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WaterState
{       
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean run = true;
        while(run)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("What is the temperature in degrees Celsius?");
            double temp = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is the height above Sea level? in exact meters");
            double altitude = scan.nextDouble(); 

            int freezingPoint = 0;
            double alternateAltitude = temp - (altitude * 0.001);
            double boilingPoint = 100;
            int baseAltitude = 300;

            if ((temp <= freezingPoint) && (altitude <= baseAltitude))
            {
                System.out.println("Water is frozen");
            }
            else if ((temp > freezingPoint) && (altitude <= baseAltitude))
            {
                System.out.println("Water is liquid");
            }
            else if ((temp >= boilingPoint) && (altitude <= baseAltitude))
            {
                System.out.println("Water is gaseus");
            }

            else if ((altitudeChange > )
            {  

                System.out.println("Water is boiling, but at a lower temperature because of the altitude");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question exactly, but I'm guessing you're looking for something like `if (altitude > 300 && temp >= boilingPoint - 1)`

Comment: And simply change boilingPoint if altitude is > baseAltitude.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels While it's true that no one answers questions based on the question's labeled "urgency", I don't think it's really *unfair* to anyone. It's just plain void.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja: regardless, 1) I give the information to help them in future questions, 2) I gave him the answer, and 3) that down-vote is not mine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't make any comment on your points 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is relative to your question:

```
        else if ((altitudeChange > ){ 
            System.out.println("Water is boiling, but at a lower temperature because of the altitude");
        }
```

And according to your input:

> if the altitude is more than 300, it takes 1 less degree celsius for
>   the water to boil and the outcome can be determined depending on the
>   input

Is this is what you want:

```
if(altitude >=baseAltitude  && temp>(boilingPoint -(altitude/baseAltitude *1)) ){//1.altitude is more than 300,2.temp is higher than the new degree celsius to boil 
 System.out.println("Water is boiling, but at a lower temperature because of the altitude");
}
```